# A Chevy Silverado on Mars

Tags: planets

Another topic that no one seems to consider is driving a 4x4 truck across the surface of Mars, years of experimenting with a robot vehicle when you have 100 years of progress with the motorcar.

So you have a fuel laden Chevy Silverado with air tanks for the fuel/air mixture and you set it on a course to drive a long distance photographing the terrain as it goes, even deploy a drill that is powered by the enging. The result is a quicker mapping of the surface, sampling and a huge coup for a motor manufacturer, the first Car on Mars.

The Opportunity Rover has travelled 40km in 10 years, a Silverado could run 400km in a couple of days.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Would [space.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Probably. It is rather more of an engineering question as is

Comment: I fail to see how it's about Space Exploration; I agree with the rejected migration.

Comment: @HDE226868 Well, see, it's about exploring mars with a pickup truck. I'd argue that's more relevant to space exploration than it is to physics

Comment: @TildalWave I'm not going to argue that this is a good question. It's just that it's better answered by the engineering or feasibility concerns of putting a truck on Mars. To us, this is too much of an engineering question. I'm not familiar enough with SX.SE but I'd have thought it was better suited there

Comment: @TildalWave Note that I answered the question; I did not ask it. I have no disagreement that it's not well-asked and that it would probably be closed if it were first posted on SX.SE. My only relevant thought processes went like this "This question is about exploring Mars with a truck. Mars is in space. Therefore this question is about exploring space and not about physics. Therefore it's better suited for spaceexploration.SE than it is for physics.SE" But I agree that it's not conforming to the right ways to ask a question

Answer (score 7):

The truck would never be able to operate on Mars. First of all, it's ridiculously heavy and inefficient to send there. Second, internal combustion engines require us to bring fuel and oxygen, which means more mass we have to bring. Third, there would not be enough air pressure to properly ventilate the truck and you couldn't close the system, so the oxygen you bring with would escape and not get used in combustion. Fourth, a truck requires a human driver, which we haven't sent to Mars. Fifth, if using a Silverado was cheaper and a better idea, we'd have done that. Sixth, a Silverado uses rubber, air-filled wheels, which is a bad idea on Mars because not only do these wear and need to be replaced, they also can pop (which they certainly would in the low pressure of Mars) and deflate. Good luck changing the tires from 450 million km away. Seventh, there are no roads on Mars, and while the Silverado may be a 4x4, the lower gravity means there is going to be a lot more displacement on the suspension system. The axle and the shock absorbers would not be able to handle the drive.

Opportunity uses an electric motor to drive across Mars. This means so long as we have a way to power it, it could (in theory) keep going. A Silverado requires fuel. Once that fuel runs out, that's it. Sending fuel to Mars is expensive. Furthermore, it's not the distance travelled that's important. Opportunity could have driven farther than 40km, but it stopped along the way to perform science experiments. Last time I checked, a Silverado doesn't have scientific equipment on it that can test the soil or the weather.

The Chevy Silverado is built to drive on Earth. Opportunity was built to drive on Mars. When it comes down to it, that's what I think most people are comfortable with. Let the Earth cars drive on Earth and the Mars cars drive on Mars

Answer (score -2):

Mars Curiosity is 899kg so a car could be sent to Mars

Fuel and Compressed Oxygen tanks isn't going to add a ridiculous amount of weight to it.

Its tires are perfect for the terrain, its built for the rocky dusty terrain too

Cars are being tested as driverless now anyway.

A drill powered by the engine would have so much more force for drilling than what is currently deployed.

You can fit the sample analyser on the truck bed at the back

Its an outlandish idea and people would be amazed if it came true

Comment: Are you here to listen to find out if a Silverado could be used on Mars? Or are you here to claim that it should be and reject the science that says otherwise? Are you a rocket scientists? Have you ever sent something to space or designed a space mission? I have done both! I am telling you that a Chevy Silverado could not have been used on Mars.